# How to control the scroll-position of a scrollviewer in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I am using a scrollviewer to show contents, and added a "DoubleTap" event to the scrollviewer. In the doubleTap event I want to make the scrollviewer automatically scroll up to the top of the scrollviewer, but I can't find any property to control the scrollviewer. any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

```
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer2" Height="auto">
                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener  DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap"/>
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel2" Height="auto">
                         <!--contents-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have properties, but you have two methods for this: ScrollToVerticalOffset (to scroll vertically) and ScrollToHorizontalOffset (to scroll horizontally).

So in your case, this code should do the trick:

```
this.scrollViewer2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
```

Comment: Note that the offset is related to the index of the ListBoxItem you want to scroll to, rather than a pixel value. It is stored as a double, e.g. 5.83 would scroll to a position between items 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that it is going to be obsolete or maybe unavailable after 8.1.
Use

```
this.scrollViewer2.ChangeView(0, 0, 1);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
this.scrollViewer2.ChangeView(null, 0, null);
```